# How to add p values for Spearman correlation coefficients plotted using pairs in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I see that there is already code available to add Pearson correlation coefficients and p values to a scatterplot matrix. Now I would simply like to add Spearman correlation coefficients in the upper panels. Currently I can add Pearson correlation coefficients by calling `upper.panel=panel.cor`, as in the below.

```
# the code for creating a scatterplot matrix
pairs(mat, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

`panel.cor` is a function supplied in a previous Stack Overflow post~

```
# panel.cor, the code for calculating coefficients and p values

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, cex.cor, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  # correlation coefficient
  r <- cor(x, y, **method="spearman"**)
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt <- paste("r= ", txt, sep = "")
  text(0.5, 0.6, txt)

  # p-value calculation
  p <- cor.test(x, y, **method="spearman"**)$p.value
  txt2 <- format(c(p, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt2 <- paste("p= ", txt2, sep = "")
  if(p<0.01) txt2 <- paste("p= ", "<0.01", sep = "")
  text(0.5, 0.4, txt2)
}
```

In an attempt to modify this for Spearman's coefficients and p values I added "method="spearman" in the two places above indicated in bold. When I ran `panel.cor` there were no error messages, but the upper panels from the code above came out blank.

I have also tried replacing cor with `rcor` from the `ltm` package and that also did not work. If I run `rcor` in place of `cor` I get the message:

> Error in lower.panel(...) : could not find function "rcor"

When I run the above line of code using `rcor.test` in place of both `cor` and `cor.test` I get the message

> Error in combn(p, 2) : n < m

Any ideas?

Comment: I used your function without problem

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Which version of R are you using?

Comment: 3.0.1 but the problem can also arise from your data instead of the function.

Comment: Something strange was floating around in my memory. When I cleared everything using rm(list=ls()) and then ran it again from scratch it indeed worked. Embarassing!

Comment: well the most important things is that you finally get what you want. See you.